# AWK parse error at END

Tags: awk

I keep getting a parse error in my code at the end

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\hafwork\hafLatest\CRM>AWK.EXE -f testking123.awk sample.txt
awk: testking123.awk:85: END{
awk: testking123.awk:85: ^ parse error
awk: testking123.awk:90:
awk: testking123.awk:90: ^ parse error
```

This is my code:

```
BEGIN{

FS= "|"
countA=CountB=0;

}

{

id=substr($2,1,1);
++file[id]




if ($3 == "P")
{
if(countB==0){
for(dupes in B)
print B[dupes] > "Bdupes.txt"
}

else if(countA==0){
for(dupes in A)
print A[dupes] > "Adupes.txt"
}

else if(countA==countB)
i=1
while(i<countA){

printA[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
printB[i] > "mixdupes.txt"

}


if(A<B && A!=0){

i=1
while(i<(A+1)){
printA[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
printB[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
}

i=A+1
while(i<(B+1)){
print B[i]> "Bdupes.txt"


  if(id=="A"){
    A[1]=$0
    countA=1;
    countB=0;

    }

  else if (id=="B"){
    B[1]=$0
    countA=0;
    countB=1;
    }
  }
elseif ($3 == "C")
{

   if(id=="A"){
    countA++;
    A[countA]=$0
    }

else if(id=="B"){
   countB++;
    B[countB]=$0
    }






}
}

END{

for (file_id in file)
print file_id ":", file[file_id]

}
```

Could anyone tell me why this is? I have tried removing spaces etc. Im not sure whether its to do with just the end of the script or if something is wrong within the script. Pretty new to AWK so not 100% sure on it. TIA

Comment: Indenting your script would *almost always* help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually this happens because you have unmatched `{ or }`.

I just copied your code in my vim and did a `gg=G`,

you are missing two closing `}`s.

You have 15 `{` in total, but only 13 `}`.

Comment: thanks Kent. Now got the error of : fatal: attempt to use array `A' in a scalar context

Comment: So what do I need to do? Sorry I am really confused, really new to this! TIA

Comment: @user2428639 I don't know. because I don't know what do you want to do... I suggest you open a new question, there you could explain the requirement, paste your codes, point the problem, better with some example input and expected output.